# Using ArcPy/iterator to generate map when zoomed to each feature of shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

I am creating a series of maps featuring a certain set of layers (floodplain zone and critical facilities). Each map will zoom in one of our municipalities (there are 62 in total). It's an utterly repetitive process so I am trying to find a way to automate. An example of the map will be like the pictures shown below:

I zoom to the Bethlehem City, export the map

[image: first zoom]

Then I zoom to another municipality and export the map.

[image: 2ND zoom]

There must be a way to automate this. My initial thought was to iterate through feature selections using iterator in ModelBuilder. Then I got stumped on the "Zoom in" and "Export Map" steps. I couldn't even find tools that do these. But I think there shall be ways to do both of these steps through ArcPy. I wish my ArcPy skills were better, but I guess this is the kind of pain that will push me to learn more about Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not require ArcPy or ModelBuilder, although ArcPy can certainly help if you encounter more complex map series requirements.

What you describe is the use case for [Data Driven Pages](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/what-are-data-driven-pages-.htm):

> Data Driven Pages allow you to quickly and easily create a series of
>   layout pages from a single map document. A feature layer, or index
>   layer, divides the map into sections based on each index feature in
>   the layer and generates one page per index feature.

In this case your index layer will be your municipalities layer.

Once you have spent a few seconds enabling Data Driven Pages on your map, you can export it to PDF (one municipality per file or a map book of all municipality maps in one file).